# Find the domain of $3^y+2^{x^4}=2^{4x^2-1}$

Tags: functions

Find the domain of the following implicit function $3^y+2^{x^4}=2^{4x^2-1}$.

As this is a implicit function  am not able to approach.

Comment: You can make it so that it's not implicit

Comment: I can make it explicit in terms of log to the base e or ln but it gets more complicated

Comment: Do that first. What do you get? What is the domain of a logarithm?

Comment: $yln3=ln (2^{4x^2-1}-2^{x^4})$

Comment: Are we talking about the solution set of all equation satisfying pairs $(x,y)$ ? For an explicit function $y = f(x)$ the domain would be the set of $x$ values, for which the function definition was valid, or?

Comment: Okay, now we know that we cannot take the logarithm of a non-positive value, so what is inside must be greater than zero. Can you derive an inequality?

Comment: I can approach from here

Comment: Take x terms to RHS and take log base 3 for an explicit expression  with positive argument.

Comment: I got the solution, my making an making an implicit function explicit